# "key was not present in the dictionary" when using generic orleans grains

Tags: c#, orleans

Just upgraded to 1.3.0 and am having issue with generic grains.

An example interface and class that's showing this issue:

```
public interface IGenericTest<T> : IGrainWithIntegerKey
{
    Task<T> PrintType(T obj);
}



public class GenericTestGrain<T> : Grain, IGenericTest<T>
{
    public Task<T> Print(T obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TEST");
        return Task.FromResult(obj);
    }
}
```

then using it like:

```
var grain = await GrainFactory.GetGrain<IGenericTest<int>>(0); // Runs without error.
await grain.Print(1);
```

Getting the grain seems to be fine, but when I call the method on the grain I get:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Orleans.InterceptedMethodInvokerCache.GetInterfaceToImplementationMap(Int32 interfaceId, Type implementationType)
at Orleans.InterceptedMethodInvokerCache.CreateInterceptedMethodInvoker(Type implementationType, Int32 interfaceId, IGrainMethodInvoker invoker)
at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
at Orleans.InterceptedMethodInvokerCache.GetOrCreate(Type implementationType, Int32 interfaceId, IGrainMethodInvoker invoker)
at Orleans.Runtime.InsideRuntimeClient.InvokeWithInterceptors(IAddressable target, InvokeMethodRequest request, IGrainMethodInvoker invoker)
at Orleans.Runtime.InsideRuntimeClient.<Invoke>d__57.MoveNext()
```

Is there something I'm missing? Maybe some new configuration? This worked fine with the previous version I was using.

EDIT:

Seems like it's an issue with the invoke interceptor:

providerRuntime.SetInvokeInterceptor((method, request, grain, invoker) =>
{
    return invoker.Invoke(grain, request);
});

When that's removed everything works.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Orleans: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/2358

Answer (score 0):

The question was answered here: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/2358
It is a bug.